# Why empty IP address resolves computer name as 204.204.204.204?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, winsock

If I execute command `ping ""` or `tracert ""` it resolve my current computer name.
But when I execute below code it resolves computer name as '204.204.204.204'

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

void get_computer_name(const std::string& ip_address, std::string& computer_name)
{
    WSADATA wsa_data;
    u_short port = 27015;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_address;
    char service_info[NI_MAXSERV] = {};
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa_data);
    socket_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    const auto error_code = InetPtonA(AF_INET, &ip_address[0], &socket_address.sin_addr.s_addr);

    socket_address.sin_port = htons(port);
    computer_name.resize(NI_MAXHOST);
    getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &socket_address,
            sizeof(socket_address),
            &computer_name[0],
            NI_MAXHOST, service_info, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);
    WSACleanup();
}

int main(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    std::string computer_name;
    get_computer_name("", computer_name);
    std::cout << computer_name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am curious about why 204.204.204.204?

Comment: ok will update the code.

Comment: `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` should be `sizeof(socket_address)`. You also need to check the values returned.

Comment: Why aren't you checking the return values of these functions? You just assume that they succeed and that their results are meaningful, but this is not assuredly true.

Comment: You should always check if the function was executed successfully `InetPtonA` returns `1` if an error occurred. And `204` corresponds to `0xCC` which - for certain compiles and environments -  could indicated uninitialized memory in debug mode.

Comment: This ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have updated the code

Comment: Your update does not at all address my comment.

Comment: @Ron: I'm not a Windows dev :P

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I will update mentioned code

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, I understand the cause of 204 :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks buddy :)

Comment: You need to read documentation for **each** function called and figure out how to properly check returned value. `if (error_code)` is no good.

Comment: @Mayur is my assumption right that you don't get `204.204.204.204` anymore with the code you currently show in your question? If yes you should not do those kind of changes to your question, because then code does not reflect the problem of the question anymore making the answers wrong and _"useless"_.

Comment: @t.niese oh, yes. I have restored the code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

204 is `0xCC`, a common placeholder for uninitialised memory on some platforms.

I wouldn't put too much stock in this value. The real problem is that you're not checking the return values for any of those API functions, so if they "fail", and their results are thus meaningless, you did not detect that.

I strongly suspect that this is the case here, so you're basically just observing nonsense (probably the result of passing a completely uninitialised `sockaddr_in` to `getnameinfo` in a debug build).

> If no error occurs, the InetPton function returns a value of 1 and the buffer pointed to by the pAddrBuf parameter contains the binary numeric IP address in network byte order.
>
> **The InetPton function returns a value of 0 if the pAddrBuf parameter points to a string that is not a valid IPv4 dotted-decimal string or a valid IPv6 address string.** Otherwise, a value of -1 is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling the
>   WSAGetLastError for extended error information.
>
> *([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inetptonw))*

Answer (score 4):

Uninitialized variable got this value in debug in VS by default.

[image]

Comment: @drescherjm This is very helpful Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It resolves 204.204.204.204 because of the combination of: (1) an uninitialized `socket_address`, (2) an empty `ip_address`, and (3) Debug-configuration [Visual Studio C++]: **-->** Uninitialized `socket_address` has a mere value (204.204.204.204 by chance because of Debug-configuration), **-->** `InetPtonA` fails (because of empty `ip_address`), and therefore **-->** `socket_address` doesn't changed.

Initialize `socket_address` with 0:

```
struct sockaddr_in socket_address; memset(&socket_address, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
```

& it doesn't resolve 204.204.204.204 anymore. It says that 204 is the default value for uninitialized variables in Debug-configuration, but I wouldn't count on that value. In Release-configuration without initialization, it's a mere junk:

[image]

--

To `get_computer_name` properly, use the proper `ip_address`. The second parameter of `netPtonA` should contain *"A pointer to the NULL-terminated string that contains the text representation of the IP address to convert to numeric binary form."* [MSDN]. Something like that:

```
int main()
{
    std::string ip("127.0.0.1"), cn;

    get_computer_name(ip, cn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with the ip address is not initialized (it is initialized with an empty string)?  Do you mean that `ip` is not `127.0.0.1`, but an empty string?  If so then yes, but the OP is wondering why the result is  `204.204.204.204` if  `ip` is an empty string. If it is about `cn("");` vs  `cn;` that should not make any difference.

Comment: @t.niese I hope now I explain myself better